# c# wpf TextBlock is sometimes not displaying Evaluated Value

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a Custom Control which basically displays the count of Rows displayed inside a DataGrid (teleriks RadDataGrid).

I can use it as follows:

```
<utility:GridFooter Grid.Row="2" SourceGrid="{Binding ElementName=GrdResult}" />
```

In the `ControlTemplate` of `GridFooter` I am Binding the `Count`-Property to a TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SourceGrid.Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                            Converter={StaticResource IntToFormatStringConverter}, ConverterParameter=N0}" />
```

This is the Converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(string))]
public class IntToFormatStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return "0";
        var i = (int) value;

        var format = parameter as string;
        if (format == null)
            return i.ToString(culture);

        // I have set a breakpoint here, and the value is alaways 
        // correct, even if its not what is beeing displayed
        // So, It's not the Converter
        var ret = i.ToString(format, culture);
        return ret;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

So I took one step further and looked up the `TextBlock` with VS2015 *Live Visual Tree*. In the *Live Property Explorer* the `Text`-Property has a BindingExpression. Upon Expansion of the `Text`-Property the *Evaluated Value* is **alaways displayed correctly!**

I'm going to make a few examples.

- `TextBlock.Text` Evaluated Value: `"11"`, Displayed in the UI: `1`
- `TextBlock.Text` Evaluated Value: `"325"`, Displayed in the UI: `3`

It seems like in error-case, only the first character of the Evaluated Value is being displayed. Also to Say: The Evaluated Value aka. `Grid.Items.Count` is correct. So I see `325` Items in the List, the Evaluated Value of `TextBox.Text`is `"325"` and it is displayed as `3`.

> The above behavior only happens sometimes. I am using `GridFooter` in multiple places with no problem, but also no significant difference.

If anyone knows this issue or has any possible fix to this, please let me know.

#### Edit:

I noticed, that upon redraw the value is displayed correctly. If e.g. the `GridFooter` was used inside a control which enables placing and docking it, moving it only a bit will cause redrawing and instantly show the missing numbers.

Also I found the workaround, that changing `Width="Auto"` to a fixed value like `Width="60"` will stop that error. However I still wonder, what causes wrong drawing.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might be a clipping issue (i.e. the textbox isn't filling all available space, so only the first character shows up), try this:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Path=SourceGrid.Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                            Converter={StaticResource IntToFormatStringConverter}, ConverterParameter=N0}" />
```

The key part being the **`HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`** attribute.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow, but it seems strange, the Control is able to Display like 20'000 and stuff.

Comment: @LuckyLikey perhaps try dropping the culture parameter from your `.ToString(format,culture)` call as well. That could be causing some odd issues.

Comment: Hey, I tried your fix. I can tell it is definitely not a clipping issue, because opon binding reload, every value can be displayed. And as explained in the Question, I have verified the result of `.ToString(format,culture)` to be correct. Otherways, the Evaluated Value of the Binding could not be correct, too. So what ever happens, seems to be a TextBlock-Bug.